# Remove all spaces greater than one in Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, whitespace

I have this code that works for a string, but need to apply it to a pandas column.  Any ideas?

```
foo = "hey     how are \n you doing today?"
foo = " ".join(foo.split())
```

output:

```
print(foo)
hey how are you doing today?
```

How to I apply this on a whole column of text within pandas?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str.replace`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['how  are you?', 'This is a good   example']})
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('\s{2,}', ' ', regex=True)


    col
0   how are you?
1   This is a good example
```

Answer (score 4):

`str.replace` is the way to go:

```
 df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
```